# Google Sheet using Python (Updated)

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-sheets, tableau-api, tableau-desktop

Trying to Write a Python Script to export dashboard data into Google sheet(This will go into Automation)

Before start let you guys know I am completely new to python, started just a month back.
I trying to export data from dashboard on server to google sheet.
Script: I have changed some sensitive info to placeholders

```
I replace view_name with all sort of id's or name i can find but still give same output

Thanks
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this through an API integration with Tableau, but if you have access to the data why not just export to Google Sheets using an SQL query?

Comment: Yes we tried but some calculations only tableau can do, can't achieve that with SQL

Comment: I am updating code again please review once, i am facing issue with panda now

Answer (score 0):

VizQL, Tableau's proprietary language, is fully interactable with SQL.

Thank you for updating the code! That error generally means the CSV isn't being recognized as a CSV. I would check delimitators in the data you're trying to upload.